# HermesJMS - Linked Exception : null when attempting to post an XML message

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am using HermesJMS version 1.14. I am attempting to post an XML message to an IBM WebSphere MQ queue via HermesJMS.

I face two issues namely,

1. If I select a queue, right click, select "New" -> "Message" and then copy , paste the xml message as a text in the 'Payload' tab, it gives me an 'MQ Authentication Error, invalid security credentials'. However, I have very well supplied the security credentials before actually pasting the payload.
2. If I click on the X button (a visual indication to upload) and select an XML message (xml file in filesystem), it gives me an error stating that "Linked Exception : null".

I have been searching (googling) for about a week's time. I had also posted the same in HermesJMS forum yesterday.

Any idea on this would be highly appreciable.